# Nested dynamic route and shallow routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next-router

Consider a dynamic route `/home/[slug]/account/[onboarding]`, the `/account/[onboarding]` route renders an onboarding modal. For example `/home/trades/account/sign-in` route should render a `trades.tsx` on /home/trades route. and `/home/trades/account/sign-in` renders the onboarding modal on top of the trades page. the goal is to be able to render the onboarding modal on top of the respective page on every route that ends with `/account/[onboarding]`.

It works fine on the root route `/` -> `/account/[onboarding]`, but not on the nested dynamic routes. Is it even possible to do modal navigation with shallow routing in a nested dynamic route, in this case, `/home/[slug]/account/[onboarding]`?

The expected behavior is similar to the Modal Navigation explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4W_LaotmNI).